# MySQL: подписан ли пользователь

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Есть 2 таблицы, с юзерами и с теми, на кого подписан юзер

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, -- id
  `login` varchar(25) NOT NULL default '', -- Логин
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `subscribers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL, -- id юзера
  `id_subscriber` int(11) NOT NULL -- На кого подписан юзер
)
```

Я получаю список подписок таким образом

```
SELECT us.login
FROM `subscribers` AS sub, `users` AS us
WHERE sub.id = 1 AND us.id = sub.id_subscriber
```

Результат возвращает один столбец с логинами тех, на кого подписан данный юзер

Дак вот, можно ли как-то сделать чтобы напротив каждого возвращаемого логина был флажек, подписан ли он тоже на меня?

Comment: Что-то не очень понятен вопрос... о_О 
Можете пояснить на примере, какие данные вы хотите в итоге получить?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  us.login,
  IF(us.id IN (SELECT `id` FROM `subscribers` WHERE `id_subscriber`='MY_ID'), 1, 0) AS IsMySubsciber
FROM `subscribers` AS sub, `users` AS us
WHERE sub.id = 1 AND us.id = sub.id_subscriber
```

Примерно так, вроде не накосячил. `IsMySubscriber` - говорящая переменная. Но с учетом тяжести подзапроса я бы после первого запроса собрал все ID и запросил всех своих подписчиков из них (`$sql = '... WHERE id IN '.implode(', ', $ids).' AND id_subscriber=MY_ID;'`), это должно быть легче для MySQL. Потом выводить по совпадениям в обоих массивах, соответственно.